# Google Plx SQL Script to compare tables and send email automatically

Tags: sql, google-apps-script

I am trying to set up an automatic email notification system using google plx script after two tables were compared.

Comment: Script will have to poll on a timebased trigger.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.